# How to use wpf original RibbonComboBox?

Tags: ribbon

I am playing with **System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon** But i don't know why The following RibbonComboBox did not work as expected. The problem is when i click any **comboBoxItem** inside nothing happens. And the comboBox is empty even if i made it **IsSelected="True"**(It did not jump into the box)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aYZz.jpg

```
<RibbonTab Header="Chart">
<RibbonGroup Header="Exchange">
    <RibbonComboBox x:Name="Exc" Label="Exchange">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="IDEALPRO" IsSelected="True"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="SMART"/>
        </RibbonComboBox>
    <RibbonTextBox x:Name="Pri" Label="Primary" TextBoxWidth="60"/>
    </RibbonGroup>
</RibbonTab>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like i need to use **RibbonGallery** inside the **RibbonComboBox** to make comboBox items selectable.